# Is there any way that an export-to-Excel function can be scalable?

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

Summary:  ASP.Net website with a couple hundred users.  Data is exported to Excel files which can be relatively large (~5 MB).

In the pilot phase (just a few users), we are already seeing occasional errors on the server in the exporting method.

Here's the stack trace:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.    at
System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)    at
System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)    at
System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.TrackingMemoryStream.Write(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.WriteAndCollapseBlocks(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)  at
MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.Write(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressEmulationStream.Write(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(BooleanflushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)   at 
System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)    at
System.Xml.XmlTextEncoder.Write(String text)    at
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteString(String text)    at
System.Xml.XmlText.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlAttribute.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlAttribute.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlDocument.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter xw)    at
System.Xml.XmlDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter w)    at
System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(Stream outStream)    at
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Save() in
C:\temp\XXXXXXXXXX\ExcelPackage\ExcelWorksheet.cs:line 605    at
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save() in
C:\temp\XXXXXXXXXX\ExcelPackage\ExcelWorkbook.cs:line 439    at
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save() in
C:\temp\XXXXXXXXXX\ExcelPackage\ExcelPackage.cs:line 348    at
Framework.Exporting.Business.ExcelExport.BuildReport(HttpContext context)    at
WebUserControl.BtnXLS_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
C:\TEMP\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXX\UserControls\ExportToExcel.ascx.cs:line 108    at
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)    at
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) at
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)   at
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)    at
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
---End of inner exception stack trace ---
at
System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    at
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    at
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)    at
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
ASP.XXXXXXXXXXX_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\TemporaryASP.NET
Files\XXXX\cdf32a52\d1a5eabd\App_Web_enxdwlks.1.cs:line 0    at
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    at
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Even aside from this particular problem, in general exporting to Excel requires the instantiation of huge Excel objects on the server for each request, which I've always assumed to mean disqualifies Excel for "serious" work on a highly-loaded server.  Is there any general way to export to Excel in a "light-weight" manner?  Would simply streaming the data into a CSV file work for this?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft's OpenXML SDK?

Comment: I think so. It's someone else's app, and they're claiming that these errors are because of another component on the system using up all the memory. I can't seem to get them to accept even the *possibility* that it's because of Excel itself being a resource pig.

Comment: By the way, seems the code above is using ExcelPackage which is different from the OpenXML SDK. So moving to the latter might also be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If formatting is not an issue, I would say yes to CSV.

Another thing I noticed, you are using ExcelPackage. I ran into some issue using it with large files. I think It was the way it handled xml and exporting large files was really slow. I would recommend using some other library.

Comment: It should also not be too much work to write your own library: Use a template .xlsx file with the styles and formatting you need and simply fill the data using an `XmlWriter` and the `System.IO.Packaging` namespace.

Comment: @OxA3: I agree that this shouldn't be terribly difficult. I'm trying to get my co-workers to accept that maybe they need to export their data some other way.

Comment: It was just that, larger the file size it was slower to export. When I profiled the code it came down to a single method to do with handling xml.

Comment: I found this similar problem: http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=26125

Comment: But no responses. I'm guessing that's because most programmers are sane and don't try to create gigantic Excel files like this.

Comment: XML is such an absolute curse on humanity. It's like a truffle, only with bubonic plague inside instead of a cherry.

Answer (score 1):

I would offload this to another machine.  Create a Windows Service that takes the command, generates the file, zips it up, saves it to disk and then returns the path to the file so that the web app can serve it.  This is one of those really memory intensive operations that you don't want bogging down your web server.

Comment: Unfortunately, this all has to be on one machine (for bureaucratic rather than technological reasons).

Comment: @MusiGenesis:  You could still go the Windows Service route because then it would at least be in a different app domain.  Otherwise, I'd go the CSV route or the route 0xA3 suggested.

Comment: amen to your last sentence - I definitely *don't* want this bogging down my web server. I've worked with web apps that export to Excel since 1998, and *all* of them have crashed the server at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is really old but if you are using the ExcelPackage I kept getting the Out of memory exception on my "LoadFromDataTable" call for a datatable which had about 300k rows. I found for me the point was about 100k where the error would ocassionally occur.

I used a split datatable method at about 50k and iterated through the datatable collection and then called the "LoadFromDataTable" method. Seems to be working only problem is the method deletes the previous. If I could figure out how to append I would be alright. Excel exports at its finest I tell you.